# Keep nan values when resampling using GEE and Python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, masking

I'm processing MODIS GPP data using GEE and python. The issue is the resolution of MODIS is very coarse so I need to upsample it using, for instance, bilinar resampling. The problem is MODIS contains some nodata values that I want to preserve (GEE mask them and I want to do the same).

For example. Using the GEE code editor:

```
var i_date = '2021-01-09';
var f_date = '2021-01-10';

var bbox = [70858, 203860, 77503, 209449];
var proj = ee.Projection("EPSG:31370");
var ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(bbox, proj, true, false);

// Get MODIS GPP and filter collection by date
var gpp = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD17A2H");
var gpp = gpp.filter(ee.Filter.date(i_date, f_date)).first().select("Gpp").clip(ROI);

var gpp_resampled = gpp.resample('bilinear').reproject({
  crs: gpp.projection(),
  scale: 50
});

Map.setCenter(3.286, 51.1654, 13)
Map.addLayer(gpp_resampled);
```

You can see that at the borders of that Image there's some missing pixels that are masked.

However, when I use python and call, for example, `plt.imshow(gpp)` or analize the content of the gpp variable, you will see that the the masked values were lost in the process. This does not happen if I don't resample the image (in this case the resulting gpp ndarray is still masked).

```
import ee
import requests
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bbox = [70858, 203860, 77503, 209449]
proj = ee.Projection('EPSG:31370')
resolution = 50
ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(bbox, proj, True, False)

# Get MODIS GPP and filter collection by date
gpp = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD17A2H")
gpp = gpp.filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-01-09', '2021-01-10')).first().select("Gpp")
gpp_resampled = gpp.resample('bilinear').reproject(crs=gpp.projection(), scale=resolution)

url = gpp_resampled.getDownloadUrl(
    {
        "bands": "Gpp",
        "crs": 'EPSG:31370',
        "region": ROI,
        "scale": resolution,
        "format": "GEO_TIFF",
    }
)

# Get information from URL and return its content
response = requests.get(url).content

# Create a file in memory not to write any file to hard disk
with MemoryFile(response) as memfile:
    with memfile.open() as src:
        raster = src.read(1)
        profile = src.profile

gpp = raster
```

So the question is do you know how to preserve the masked values after resampling just like it is showed in GEE?